# Does TfidfVectorizer keep order of the features?

Tags: scikit-learn, tf-idf

I wonder if TfidfVectorizer  keeps the order of the features when transforming documents using scikit-learn. Here is what I am doing:

```
from sklearn.feature_exteraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = ['this  movie is cool', 'I love this book']
vec = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_tranform(corpus)
joblib.dump(vec, './vec') 
doc = 'What are the coolest movies in 2015' 
vec = joblib.load('./vec')
X_test = vec.transform([doc])
```

Now, my question is that are the feature entries in X and X_test in the same order?

Comment: Note that in your example, none of the words in your test document occur in your training corpus, hence `X_test` will be all zeros (see output of e.g. `X_test.A.any()`)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. As when you call `fit()`, it creates a vocabulary dictionary from text strings to column indexes. It uses that to transform additional data sets. This is preserved in any serialization and deserialization.

```
vec.vocabulary_
> {u'book': 0, u'cool': 1, u'is': 2, u'love': 3, u'movie': 4, u'this': 5}
```